# 2-D exponential functional brownian motion

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

I'm looking for the distribution of

$X = \int_0^T e^{-W_t} dt \int_0^T e^{W_t}dt$

and

$Y = \frac{\int_0^T e^{-W_t} dt}{ \int_0^T e^{W_t}dt}$

(where $W_t$ is a standard brownian motion)

On most of the papers i find on the internet they only tackle the integrals by separte using Bougerol's identity. But not exactly the symmetric problem i'm studying with the two integrals.

thanks.